# Comparing multiple columns in EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have two Microsoft excel spreadsheet. Book1.xlsx and Book2.xlsx
in both file 8 columns.

I need to compare all columns against each other and get output like "Matched or "Unmatched".

[image]

Comment: There is a tool within Office 2013 called spreadsheet compare. Please share the operating system (Eg:Windows 7 / 10) and the Office version you are using.

Comment: Windows 7 is O.S. and Microsoft excel 2010

Comment: Click on start menu and typre `spreadsheet`.... It should show you `spreadsheet compare 2010` - if you got that installed. It is an easy way to compare spreadsheets

Comment: Thank you...but it's not available... Can you help using any formula like vlookup or any other command which compare all the columns

Comment: Ok...if i copied every column (i.e. 8 + 8 ) in book1.xlsx, then which formula will fix it, so i get that Matched or unmatched in last column. Your assistance will be great help.

Comment: @user769247 does my answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example range of your data in the `columns A:H`in both sheets.
`Book2` has also the same or more amount of data rows, then `book1`.

In `Book2.xlsx` and `Book1.xlsx` insert in cell `I2` (the first row with data) formula:

```
=A2&B2&C2&D2&E2&F2&G2&H2
```

In `Book2.xlsx` insert in cell `J2` formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(I2;[Book1.xlsx]yourSheetName!$I:$I;1;FALSE));"unmatch";"match")
```

fill down the cells with formulas in both sheets.

Comment: error occurred while using    =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(I2;[Book1.xlsx]yourSheetName!$I:$I;1;FALSE));"unmatch";"match")

Comment: put `yourSheetName` into formula

Answer (score 0):

This approach requires you to combine both workbooks into a single workbook (different sheets is fine)! By this I mean copy the entire sheet from Workbook2 into Sheet2 of Workbook 1.

Then the approach is to simply `CONCATENATE` each cell for both tables and then use `SUMIF`

Consider my data which represents what you have. Workbook1 is the top 3 rows. I've copied worksheet 2 underneath (starting at row 9). The middle row of each table is the row which doesn't match.

[image]

In G1, I've added the following code

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1)
```

And I have copied that all the way down

[image]

Now we can simply compare which rows match. For the last 3 rows, I added

```
=COUNTIF(G$1:G$3, G9)
```

[image]

Finally, wrap an IF statement

```
=IF(COUNTIF(G$1:G$3, G9)>0, "Matched", "Unmatched")
```

[image]

You may or may not want that if statement. The SUMIF will count all occurances, meaning it will show if there is 1, 2, 3, 4 etc matches. The if statement will only show that there is at least 1 match.